# "Advice I wish I'd had ears to hear" — is this phrase in common use? Origins?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms, word-usage, metaphors

Productivity writer [Merlin Mann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_Mann) often uses the phrase "ears to hear" on his [podcast](http://5by5.tv/b2w/). An [example](http://www.43folders.com/2010/05/17/future-proofing-your-passion) from his writing:

> "a discursive mishmash of advice I wish I'd had the ears to hear in the year or five after graduating from college"

Clearly, this means "advice I wish I'd been ready enough, or open minded enough to listen to".

Is this a common idiom? I've not come across it elsewhere.

Does it have any particular origins? I wonder whether it's related to [this Bible verse](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Matthew-11-15/):

> "He that hath ears to hear, let him hear."

Comment: Probably does. I've not heard it used in that way before.

Answer (score 2):

The *ear* in this particular verse in Greek is:

> **G3775**
>
> ous
>
> ooce
>
> Apparently a primary word; the ear (physically or
> mentally): - ear.

If Merlin Mann patterned the phrase *ears to hear* from the Bible, it just means literal ear. I am not familiar with the usage of this as a common idiom, if it is indeed an accepted idiom.

But if I were to understand that phrase, I would have the same understanding as you. I cannot think of any meaning, but it may still depend on the context or on the adjacent sentences. I cannot see any *mystery* or hidden meanings behind the phrase you quoted.

I provided the Greek meaning of the word because the Bible is originally written in Greek, Hebrew or Aramaic, depending on the book.